# Hide and show code is not working in chrome

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, browser-compatibility

This code is working in IE browser but not working in Chrome browser what changes should me made to make it compatible on both the browsers

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"
    $(document).ready(function(){

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
$("select[title='Regional']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Regional']").val() != "No") 
{
$('nobr:contains("Document Name")').closest('tr').hide();
} 
else 
{
$('nobr:contains("Document Name")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into script editor web part in the new/edit form page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"
$(function () {
    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
    $("select[title='Regional']").change(function() {
        if($(this).val()!="No"){
            $('nobr:contains("Document Name")').closest('tr').hide();
        }else{
            $('nobr:contains("Document Name")').closest('tr').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If it will not work in chrome, please using F12 to check if some error occurs.

[image]

If you open the page in chrome in SharePoint modern UI, your code will not works.